# Turn off Auto Scroll in JQuery UI Auotcomplete

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

When I use JQuery Autocomplete and have enough results to show a scroll bar I mouse over the bottom of the dropdown and it automatically scrolls down. This also happens when I scroll down and then hover over the very top of the list it will automatically scroll up. I am seeing this in Chrome.

You can see it happening in this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/LesignButure/EVsye/

How can I turn this off?

Here is my css:

```
ul.autocomplete-menu
{
position: absolute;
cursor: default;
border: thin solid #C0C0C0;
list-style: none;
padding: 2px;
margin: 0;
display: block;
float: left;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
color: #000000;
max-height: 200px;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apparently the padding:2px; was causing the issue. Changing to padding-left:2px seemed to fix it.